# Updating array of objects in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

I'm trying to update an array of objects in my simple-schema. Currently, it removes everything in the database and leaves behind:

`"careerHistoryPositions": []`

My [simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema) looks like:

```
const ProfileCandidateSchema = new SimpleSchema({
      userId: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id
      },
      careerHistoryPositions: { type: Array, optional: true },
      'careerHistoryPositions.$': { type: Object, optional: true },
      'careerHistoryPositions.$.uniqueId': { type: String, optional: true },
      'careerHistoryPositions.$.company': { type: String, optional: true },
      'careerHistoryPositions.$.title': { type: String, optional: true }
    });
```

If console.log form data looks like:

```
 careerHistoryPositions:  [Object, Object],
    0: Object
    company: "Test company"
    title: "Test Title"
    uniqueId: 1498004350350
    1: Object
    company: "Test company 2"
    title: "Test Title 2"
    uniqueId: 149800433221
```

My update function:

```
handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { careerHistoryPositions } = this.state;

    ProfileCandidate.update({ _id: this.state.profileCandidateCollectionId },
      { $set: {
        careerHistoryPositions
      }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your schema has `$` in the field names? I don't think it does. If it "really does" as you have defined it, then you are doing it **wrong**. The `$` is reserved in this context for the [positional `$` operator.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/). I think you need to show the full conext of the actual code you have implemented since you are either misrepresenting or misunderstanding how this all works.

Comment: I've updated the full schema, it's based on simple-schema package (see link). I'm happy to put up more code but I'm not sure what else I could put up. Please advise.

Comment: I don't like how SimpleSchema handles this, as it's just not very "MongoDB" like. A better approach to defining schema would be as demonstrated with [Combining Schemas](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#combining-simpleschemas). As such then you should also be following the official documentation for the positional `$` operator (link already given) for the actual update. Where if you want to `$set` a matched element you also need to specify the `"uniqueId"` or something to match the array element within the "query" portion of the `.update()`. All covered in the documentation link.

Comment: Thanks, @Neil. Still learning. Your references are great but they are to the wrong documentation. I'm using Simple-Schema V2 - https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema

Comment: I know. I linked to "Combining Schemas" from the SimpleSchema docs, in my comment. You should be clicking on those links and reading them. I'm too busy to look into this now, so you should be doing that in between now and if/when someone gives you an answer.

Comment: OK. Thanks for that. I'll keep rereading.

Comment: Hi Niel. Figured I throw this at you. Everything I read keeps leading me back to [Schema keys]( https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema#schema-keys). Isn't this what I've done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by mapping over my object and running 2 separate updates. The first removes the old element and the second adds the updated version. I'm sure there is a better way to do this, however, this does seem to work.

```
handleFormSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const { careerHistoryPositions } = this.state;

  ProfileCandidate.update({_id: this.state.profileCandidateCollectionId}, { $unset: {
    'careerHistoryPositions': {}
  }
})        


const updatePosition = this.state.careerHistoryPositions.map((position) => {
  ProfileCandidate.update({_id: this.state.profileCandidateCollectionId}, { $push: {
    'careerHistoryPositions': {
      company: position.company,
      title: position.title,
      uniqueId: position.uniqueId
    }
  }
})
```