# Collection2 update function filters out keys

Tags: mongodb, meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

My MongoDB, [collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2-core) update function keeps throwing the error `After filtering out keys, not in the schema, your modifier is now empty`. I've been told that my schema isn't correct, however, I read the documentation and as far as I can tell I've implemented the schema as recommended.

My [simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema#subschemas) looks like:

```
const ProfileCandidateSchema = new SimpleSchema({
      userId: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id
      },
      careerHistoryPositions: { type: Array, optional: true },
      'careerHistoryPositions.$': { type: Object, optional: true },
      'careerHistoryPositions.$.uniqueId': { type: String, optional: true },
      'careerHistoryPositions.$.company': { type: String, optional: true },
      'careerHistoryPositions.$.title': { type: String, optional: true }
    });
```

My update function based on collection2:

```
const updatePosition = this.state.careerHistoryPositions.map((position) => {    
ProfileCandidate.update(this.state.profileCandidateCollectionId, {$set: {
          'careerHistoryPositions': {
                  'company': position.company,
                  'title': position.title,
                  'uniqueId': position.uniqueId
                }
        }})
  });
```

Comment: Patience. Please don't post the same question again. Your present question in unanswered so feel free to edit more detail into that instead.

Comment: Edit your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44665009/2313887) with more details, updates, whatever. the point is not to post what is basically the same thing again.